# Is it possible to reset calls history, but persist behavior?

Tags: javascript, sinon

I would like to write a default mock like this one:

```
const myStub = sinon.stub().withArgs('myArg').returns('someValue');
```

And in my tests I just want to reset calls history of `myStub` in `beforeEach` handler, but keep its default behavior. So I don't need to reassign it every time I want to use it.

I know there is `reset` method, which resets stub completely and `resetBehavior` that resets behavior of a stub. But do we have some method that can reset only calls history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official docs http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/stubs/ for `stub.reset`:

> Resets both behaviour and history of the stub.
>
> This is equivalent to calling both stub.resetBehavior() and
>   stub.resetHistory()

Just try `stub.resetHistory()`

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed this in docs, may be read some prev version... thx! Will try this